# Fast Arbiters for On-Chip Network Switches

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, logic-gates

For "[Fast Arbiters for On-Chip Network Switches](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.987&rep=rep1&type=pdf)", what is the difference between Proposed-I and Proposed-II topologies?

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: Well, their connection topologies are different. [Fast Arbiters for On-Chip Network Switches](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.987&rep=rep1&type=pdf) looking at figures 7 and 8, Proposal II is faster.

Comment: @user8352 what do you understand by [GP and GR](https://i.imgur.com/SG72vpa.png) ?